# jekyll build fails: permissions denied @ dir_s_mkdir

Tags: ruby, jekyll

My jekyll blog apparently includes folders under `/_site`, and that seems to cause problems:

```
$ jekyll build


Configuration file: /Users/Max/Github/maxheld83.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/Max/Github/maxheld83.github.io
       Destination: /Users/Max/Github/maxheld83.github.io/_site
      Generating... 
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/Max/Github/maxheld83.github.io/_site/2005
```

I have no idea what's going on here.

`sudo` solves the problem, but I don't want to always use it (and *can't* inside [`servr::jekyll`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/servr/index.html)).

I got:

- jekyll 2.5.3

Comment: How did you install jekyll on your system? What is the output of: `ls -lah \`which jekyll\``?

Comment: I installed it via `gem install jekyll` a while back, and then again yesterday, with updates and all.
Output: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin   504B Aug 18 22:03 /usr/local/bin/jekyll`

Any thoughts how `/_site` got the weird permissions (below) to begin with?

Comment: Looks like the owner of jekyll is not your user (unless you do everything as root). Try and uninstall it and reinstall it as your user, then you won't have to sudo. You can delete the `_site/` folder as you like, jekyll will rebuild it when you do `jekyll build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `/_site` and its subdirectories and files owner, group, and permissions. Maybe You ran Jekyll with sudo at some point so the owner got messed up.

Answer (score 2):

gynter over at [Jekyll Talk](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/jekyll-build-fails-permissions-denied-dir-s-mkdir/1119) solved the issue:

The `/_site` directory had weird permissions; read/write only for `system`, but not my user account.

Deleting `/_site` and creating it again with appropriate permissions solved the issue.

No idea how this arose in the first place, though.